# How to sort a MySQL query by a mathematical relation between multiple columns in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am developing a MySQL DB for an online jewelry shopping website. Every jewelry may have different stones, metals, … Their net prices will change everyday (e.g., every ounce of gold may be X today and Y tomorrow). Product A may be more expensive than B today, but cheaper tomorrow. Every time a user requests the products list, the website automatically calculates the price of every product.

How can users sort products by its price, considering that net price is not stored in a field in DB and every time will be calculated (using weights, net fees, …) by a function named `func($id)`, where `$id` is the id of the product.

An illustration to the question:

[image: Database example]

Comment: I googled my question many times. And cant find any peculiar solution. Plz read it before hitting -1!!!!

Comment: You say "website automatically calculates the price" -- how? And why can't you do the sorting there? If it's not in MySQL then MySQL can't sort it.

Comment: As @Samsquanch said, you cannot sort something with MySQL unless the value is in MySQL. Are you storing the products in an array? Have you looked at PHP's array sorting functions?

Comment: You may want to post the schema and the SQL queries you are doing now. If they're long put them on Pastebin.

Comment: "website automatically calculates the price" means a Function calculates the price and the price is not stored in a field. The price is calculated by a mathematical relation between columns of a table.

Comment: How? You haven't explained any of your methods. You can have my '-1' because you have nothing explained properly. Also flagged as 'low quality'.

Comment: @ImanHejazi You should also be using MySQLi code, not MySQL, if you are not doing so.

Comment: SELECT x.weight*y.value AS price FROM my_table x JOIN my_other_table y ON y.thing = x.thing ORDER BY price

Comment: The answer is sort with PHP since you do the calculation in PHP.

Comment: Use @Strawberry's answer and if you need external parameters (gold price,...) put them into query: `$sql = "SELECT ({$gold_price} * products.gold_amount + ...) AS net_price ... ORDER BY net_price";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have all of your data in your DB, there is no reason you can't `ORDER BY` any kind of expression you want.

If, say, you had a table `products (pid, name)`, `productContents (pid, type, amount)`, and `contentPrices (type, price)`, you could run something like

```
SELECT a.name, SUM(b.amount*c.price) AS totalPrice FROM products a 
    LEFT JOIN productContent b ON a.pid = b.pid
    LEFT JOIN contentPrices c ON b.type=c.type
    ORDER BY totalPrice DESC;
```

---

EDIT to work with the updated question schema:

```
SELECT p.title, p.metal_weight*m.fee + p.stone_weight*s.fee AS totalPrice FROM Products p
    LEFT JOIN Metals m ON p.metal_id=m.id
    LEFT JOIN Stones s ON p.stone_id=s.id
    ORDER BY totalPrice DESC;
```

Comment: OP says it's not in the DB.

Comment: Then OP should fix that, if he wants a functioning website.

Comment: He says that net price is not a field in the db - no more than totalPrice is in this answer.  Assuming the underlying data is in the db then you can sort by a computed field as shown

Comment: Thanks a lot, Everyone is on hurry to push -1, rather than solving problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two ways, but first of all, if you want a good performance, store the price value in a Field. I don't think it changes every second, does it?

So first, if you can make your Price calculator function in MySQL, create a Stored Procedure for it and run this on the table periodically (for example every day at 00:00) and store the value in a field. You can find how to schedule an event in MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html).

If you can't do this, stay with php, but it also should called periodically to calculate everything. You can do it with cron on Unix (if you have the rights). This can be scheduled on a remote server too, so if you have somewhere a server where you can use cron, simply call the updater.php with wget, for example:

```
wget -c http://jewerly-shop.com/update_prices.php && rm -rf update_prices.php
```

But if you need further help, we need more info (like the function that does the calculating and the table structures).